# Handling paste by mouse. When pasting with ctrl + v the event.target.value is set to whatever string I pasted but when pasting but mouse it is not

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, paste

When pasting into an input field of my widget with ctrl + v the `event.target.value` where `event` is an `keyup` event is set to whatever string I pasted. When doing paste by mouse using context menu `event.target.value` whever `event` is an `paste` event whatever was in the input field before pasting, not what I want to paste.

Is it any common issue, how to handle the paste event after the contents are in the input field?

Answer (score 0):

The `paste` event fires first, then `event.target.value` changes. That's why you get old value. Look here for the details https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/

You can handle it with `addEventListener` for paste event and operating with `clipboardData`. Look through example below.

```js
document.getElementById('testPaste2').addEventListener('paste', function(ev){
  if(ev.clipboardData.types.indexOf('text/plain') > -1){
    alert(ev.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'));
  }
});
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
  inputs[i].addEventListener('keyup', function(ev){
    alert(this.value)
  });
}
```

```html
<p><label for="testPaste1">Without event listener <input type="text" id="testPaste1"></label></p>
<p><label for="testPaste2">With event listener <input type="text" id="testPaste2"></label></p>
```